# Where can I find one-handed piano pieces?

Tags: piano, repertoire

I have sustained an injury in my right hand from playing the piano (my doctor diagnosed it as "tennis elbow"). Where can I find pieces that are suitable for left hand only? Hopefully they are sorted by difficulty.

Comment: Really, you must have very poor technique if you had an injury while playing piano. Do you learn with a teacher or on your own? Concerning your request for left hand pieces, what's your level?

Comment: With a teacher; perhaps the injury is a result several other factors... my level is beginner-intermediate

Comment: Maybe you are not relaxed enough when you sit at the piano to play. Or you play for too long and strain yourself unconsciously. Anyway, add your level in the OP so that people have an idea as to what they can advise you. Also, try a search because I think someone had a similar question.

Comment: [For instance](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/609/what-are-some-good-intermediate-level-pieces-for-piano-left-hand).

Comment: I saw this question. It only deal for a specified level. my question is encompassing on purpose in order to create a list of list of works. This would be great for me, but also for people who can only play with one Hand always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of pieces for left-hand only piano. I'm only familiar with CPE Bach's [Solfegietto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfeggietto) (I'm not sure if it was originally written for left-hand piano or 2-hand piano), but a quick IMSLP search brings up [a sizeable list of left-hand pieces.](http://imslp.org/wiki/List_of_Piano_works_for_the_left_hand)

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, IMSLP has no indication of the level of the pieces; you'll have to eyeball it yourself.

Comment: I have also found this site for left hand alone: http://www.left-hand-brofeldt.dk/